# Why does the output have random characters at the end?

Tags: c

I was trying to solve a problem in toph.co platform. I have made a code. It is not working as it should be. Giving me the correct output in some cases. But when I am trying a case with 'o' it is entering in a loop. And maybe the problem is there. But I am unable to find that out.

Problem link: https://toph.co/p/better-passwords

Please  help me to solve the problem in my code. I am using c programming language. As I am new in programming, I am not getting the point that is wrong.

I have tried it in many ways. Modifying the code again and again. Now I am becoming mad.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char s[40], i, j;
    int len;
    gets(s);
    len= strlen(s);
    for(i=0; i<=len; i++)
    {
        if(s[i] == 's')
        {
            s[i]= '$';
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'i')
        {
            s[i]= '!';
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'o')
        {
            s[i]= '(';
            for(j=len; j>i; j--)
            {
                s[j]=s[j-1];
                len= strlen(s);
            }
            s[i+1]=')';
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
        len= strlen(s);
    }
    if (s[0]>='a' && s[0]<='z')
    {
        s[0]= s[0]- 32;
    }
    int new_len=strlen(s);
    s[new_len]='.';
    puts(s);
    return 0;
}
```

I expect the output Un$()ph!$t!cated. , but it is showing Un$()ph!$t!cated.....'Many unwanted charecter'.....

Comment: `s[new_len]='.';` overwrites the null character that marks the end of the string, and then `puts` does not know where the string ends. Put a new null character after the period with `s[new_len+1] = 0;`. Make sure there is room for it in the array.

Comment: When that happens you probably overwrote the `NUL` terminator and trashed your string. Always, *always* ensure there's a zero-byte at the end of the string, and that your buffer is sufficiently large before manipulating it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have tried that. I am having the problem when I have an input containing 'o'.. I think there is something wrong in the loop there. Please check that again.

Comment: @tadman I have tried adding the 'nul' terminator. But it doesn't work. Please check the loop in my code.

Comment: `gets` has been obsolete for 20 years and was complete removed from the C language 8 years ago. Might want to look at updating your sources for learning C.

Answer (score 1):

Your string null byte is missing after manipulations, easiest way to avoid such problems - is to initialize whole character array into zero bytes:

```
char s[40] = {0}, // was char s[40], uninitialized !
```

Also do you notice a compile message "*warning: the `gets' function is dangerous and should not be used*" ?

`gets()` is dangerous, because it is not protected from buffer overflow - try to run your program with very long string exceeding your buffer `s` capacity and you will get a crash :

> *** stack smashing detected ***:  terminated Aborted (core dumped)

Use `fgets()` instead of gets(), like so :

```
fgets(s, 39, stdin);
if (s[strlen(s)-1] == '\n') s[strlen(s)-1] = '\0'; // deleting newline character
```

Notice, that we read here `BUFFER_SIZE - 1` characters here, i.e.- by 1 char less, than your buffer is able to hold (40), because if we enter long string which is of full buffer size,- then your code extending string will smash stack once again. You need to be serious about buffer overflows.

Answer (score 0):

As most commentators wrote: you don't put the end-of-string character '\0' behind the extended string. Strings in C are marked by this extra character at the end. It is needed to find the end of a string.

Example: A string "abc" is actually a sequence of 4 characters, 'a', 'b', 'c', and '\0'. Its length is 3, and its `s[3]` contains '\0'.

Your loop:

```
        for(j=len; j>i; j--)
        {
            s[j]=s[j-1];
            len= strlen(s);
        }
```

In the first turn of the loop the character at `s[len]` is replaced by the character at `s[len-1]`. This overwrites the original '\0' with the last (visible) character of your string.

If you change the loop into:

```
        for (j = len; j > i; j--)
        {
            s[j + 1] = s[j];
        }
```

the '\0' will be copied in the first run.

*Note 1: Move the assignment to `len` behind the loop.*

*Note 2: Make sure that your variable `s` is big enough for all inputs.*

*Note 3: See the whitespace I use? Adopt a good code style and stick to it.*

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of places in your code where you are overwriting the "\0".
These are:

```
s[j]=s[j-1];
```

And

```
s[new_len]='.';
```

So the rectified code would be....

```
int main()
{
    char s[40], i, j;
    int len;
    gets(s);
    len= strlen(s);
    for(i=0; i<=len; i++)
    {
        if(s[i] == 's')
        {
        s[i]= '$';
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'i')
        {
            s[i]= '!';
        }
        else if(s[i] == 'o')
        {
            s[i]= '(';
            for(j=len+1; j>i; j--) //j needs to be one more than the length
            {
                s[j]=s[j-1];
                len= strlen(s);
            }
            s[i+1]=')';
        }
        else
        {
            continue;
        }
        len= strlen(s);
    }
    if (s[0]>='a' && s[0]<='z')
    {
        s[0]= s[0]- 32;
    }
    int new_len=strlen(s); 
    s[new_len]='.';//add a '.'
    s[new_len+1] = '\0'; //add the terminating character
    puts(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Isn't the intention that `s[new_len]='.';` adds a dot to the end of the string?- in which case it needs to be before the terminator.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out....have corrected my code.......

Comment: Thank you all. My problem is solved. It was my first question is this amazing website and I am really satisfied.